# How to detect tower changes in Android?

Tags: android, cellular-network

Just wanted to know whether it's possible to get cell tower changes in Android?

I have seen an event called `onCellLocationChanged` in `PhoneStateListener`.

Can I use this to detect cell tower changes ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the correct method. It is always called if you are in a new cell. See the documentation here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#onCellLocationChanged(android.telephony.CellLocation)

**Update: November 2022**

This class was deprecated in API level 31. Use [TelephonyCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyCallback) instead.

Answer (score 5):

This is not true.
`onCellLocationChanges` from `PhoneStateListener` is ONLY called when the phone is NOT sleeping.
You have to wake up the phone (force a wakelock) - to get cell info.