# PhoneStateListener onCellLocationChanged does not get called in background

Tags: android, gsm

I've implemented a sticky-service which runs in the background. I want my app to handle gsm-Cell-changes. But my PhoneStateListener does not get called reliably. Sometimes it just gets called after i pressed a button and the phone resumes from sleep mode.
How am i able to force the phone to recognize gsm-Locationchanges reliably in a background service? Why does it sometimes work and other times not?

Comment: read 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715427/how-to-detect-tower-changes-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Put `PhoneStateListener` in the service and then put the requests for listening in the `onStartCommand`. If the service stops listening for the changes, try to create a `Timer` that calls for a `TimerTask` class inside the service which contains the listening requests and make the `Timer` call for the `TimerTask` class every X milliseconds. That worked for me.