# Best method to be notified on a cell tower change on Android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to be notified when my phone switch to another cell tower. For this, I have registered a listener on the `TelephonyManager` and get all cells infos using the method `OnCellInfoChanged` and `OnSignalStrenghChanged` (as OnCellInfoChanged always give me null as the list of `CellInfo`, when `OnSignalStrenghChanged` is called, I call the `getAllCellInfo` method from the `TelephonyManager`, so it do "the tricks")

As this listener is only called when the phone is no sleeping (cf [How to detect tower changes in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715427/how-to-detect-tower-changes-in-android) ), I'm not always notified from a cell tower change.

I don't want to build a long running service, or to check at specific interval on which tower cell I'm.

Do you know any method to be notified when an user is on a cell tower (ie: even when the phone is sleeping) ?

What I want to achieve is to notifiy the user when he is close to a specific tower cell.

Comment: Did you get any solution? Acquiring a wake lock and checking on specific interval is one possibility. But its battery expensive.