# How to detect cell tower changes in IOS?

Tags: ios, cellular-network

So it's possible to detect cell tower changes in Android ([How to detect tower changes in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715427/how-to-detect-tower-changes-in-android))

But is it possible to do so in IOS? If so, how?

Comment: There's no API in iOS for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not available in the API due to what I presume privacy concerns.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: It's not available in the API.